# Where does the LibraryLink version information come from?

Tags: librarylink

[`LibraryVersionInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LibraryVersionInformation.html) returns the following information:

```
Needs["LibraryLink`"]
lib = FindLibrary["demo"];
LibraryVersionInformation[lib]

<|"Name" -> ..., 
  "Path" -> ..., 
  "MajorVersion" -> 0, "MinorVersion" -> 0, "RevisionNumber" -> 0, 
  "WolframLibraryVersion" -> 3|>
```

Where does all this version information come from?

I assume that `WolframLibraryVersion` comes from

```c
DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) { return WolframLibraryVersion; }
```

What about `MajorVersion`, `MinorVersion` and `RevisionNumber`?  How can I set this information for my own libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is going to depend a lot on the operating system.

On Linux [(source)](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html),

> Every shared library also has a ``real name'', which is the filename containing the actual library code. The real name adds to the soname a period, a minor number, another period, and the release number. The last period and release number are optional.

for example, `libfoo.so` might be a symbolic link to `libfoo.so.1.2.3` and then the major version, minor version and release number are 1, 2 and 3.

The details of library versioning on other operating systems are being left as an exercise for the reader, but here is a brief sketch:

On OS X, the version information is stored in the [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) header. `LibraryVersionInformation` will either get it from an `otool` call (if `otool` is present) or read it directly from the header. Setting the version of a `.dylib` is done through a linker option, `-current_version` [(source)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/CreatingDynamicLibraries.html).

On Windows, the version information is stored in the [PE/COFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) header. Visual Studio, for example, has the `/VERSION` linker option [(source)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h88b7dc8) to set it. LibraryLink reads the information through a [`DllGetVersion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776404) or [`GetFileVersionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003) API call.

Comment: Ah, so it's not LibraryLink-specific at all!